# I changed the column name, now heroku db:migrate doesn't work because the column doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I changed the name of my 'image_url' column in my 'visions' table to 'image'. However, now when I try the command `heroku run rake db:migrate`, I get the error:
`PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "image_url" does not exist`

rails db:migrate works fine. 
However, heroku run rake db:migrate gives me the error.

this is my migration file for changing the column name:

```
  def change
    rename_column :visions, :image_url, :image
  end
end
```

My schema for that table:

```
    t.string "description"
    t.string "image"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_visions_on_user_id"
  end
```

Comment: Seems like the column image_url is not present on heroku. Can you confirm that with running `heroku run rails c` and check the attributes of `Vision`

Comment: Just to make sure, you pushed the migration to heroku?

Comment: do you have any previous migration files trying to set `visions.image_url` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try running `$ heroku run "bundle exec rake db:schema:dump && cat db/schema.rb"` to get the heroku schema so you can check what columns are there in Visions table.